# XSS prevention in playframework1.2.4

Tags: java, playframework

As per the [documentation on XSS](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.1.1/security) ,I included the following line in application.conf

> future.escapeInTemplates=true

In my webapp,a user can add comment to a page.A textfield accepts text input from user and saves it to the db.I entered the following line as comment

`<script> alert('hi') </script>`

This gets saved in the db as it is , and displays the same in the browser.No alert popup occurs.Does that mean the XSS problem is not occurring?
Even without adding the escapeInTemplates=true in application.conf ,the program gives the same behaviour.

There were some warnings [elsewhere](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/security/#cross-site-scripting-xss-protection) about saving unsanitized html  to database.So,should I use something like Jsoup to sanitize the user input before saving it to the db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `escapeInTemplate` does not prevent html from being saved, it escapes it when rendered in the template. From the [Play Framework 1.2.4 docs](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/security#xss):

> Play’s template engine automatically escapes strings. If you really
>   need to insert unescaped HTML in your templates, you can do so using
>   the raw() Java extension on the string. But if the string comes from a
>   user input, you need to make sure it is sanitized first.

So when the html is displayed in the template, the `<SCRIPT>` tag gets escaped to

```
&lt;SCRIPT&gt;
```